# kendo ui mvvm button data-bind enabled with function

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

I want to combine 2 variables from the viewModel.

Inside a template I have the button:

```
<a data-role="button" id="#=index#" 
   data-bind="events: { click: onAddClick }, 
              enabled: #= checkIfAddButtonEnabled(index)#">
   Add
</a>
```

and inside the same view html file I have also the function:

```
<script>
  function checkIfAddButtonEnabled(index){
    return X.details.viewModel.canAddStuff[index] && !X.details.viewModel.isStuffDisabled;
  };
</script>
```

The booleans returned by the function are correct but they are apparently not seen by the `enabled` binding.

Is this expected? Should I give up and instead add a new boolean to each object in the array that this template uses?

EDIT: I did gave up on this and used a new property in my object passed to the template instead, but my question is still valid, I still would like to know if it's possible to bind to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only one way in this case. 
You can do

```
<a data-role="button" id="#=index#" 
   data-bind="events: { click: onAddClick }, 
              enabled: checkIfAddButtonEnabled">
   Add
</a>
```

And in model something like:

```
checkIfAddButtonEnabled: function () {
  //get index and check bool value
  return value;
},
```

Comment: You're right!! I thought I had tried this and that my template couldn't see the model because its `data-bind: source` was not referring to `this`, but it seems it's working now, probably had missed something else in there!